# How to condense if statments

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a program in python that will play the game of war. I was wondering if there is a way to condense all the if statements to a simpler code. I need to pick a random number from 1-13 and those numbers relate to one of the cards in a deck. 1=Ace, 2=2 ... 11=Jack, 12=Queen, 13=King. I have not learned any functions yet so I cannot use any of those.

```
    while player_picked == computer_picked:
        player_picked = random.randint(1,13)
        computer_picked = random.randint(1,13)

        if player_picked == 1:
            card_picked_player = "Ace"
        if player_picked == 2:
            card_picked_player = "Two"
        if player_picked == 3:
            card_picked_player = "Three"
        if player_picked == 4:
            card_picked_player = "Four"
        if player_picked == 5:
            card_picked_player = "Five"
        if player_picked == 6:
            card_picked_player = "Six"
        if player_picked == 7:
            card_picked_player = "Seven"
        if player_picked == 8:
            card_picked_player = "Eight"
        if player_picked == 9:
            card_picked_player = "Nine"
        if player_picked == 10:
            card_picked_player = "Ten"
        if player_picked == 11:
            card_picked_player = "Jack"
        if player_picked == 12:
            card_picked_player = "Queen"
        if player_picked == 13:
            card_picked_player = "King"

        if computer_picked == 1:
            card_picked_computer = "Ace"
        if computer_picked == 2:
            card_picked_computer = "Two"
        if computer_picked == 3:
            card_picked_computer = "Three"
        if computer_picked == 4:
            card_picked_computer = "Four"
        if computer_picked == 5:
            card_picked_computer = "Five"
        if computer_picked == 6:
            card_picked_computer = "Six"
        if computer_picked == 7:
            card_picked_computer = "Seven"
        if computer_picked == 8:
            card_picked_computer = "Eight"
        if computer_picked == 9:
            card_picked_computer = "Nine"
        if computer_picked == 10:
            card_picked_computer = "Ten"
        if computer_picked == 11:
            card_picked_computer = "Jack"
        if computer_picked == 12:
            card_picked_computer = "Queen"
        if computer_picked == 13:
            card_picked_computer = "King"
```

Comment: use a dictionary or a list...`{1:'Ace',2:'Two',...}` or `['Ace','Two',...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list, and then index the list.

```
cards = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", ..., "King"]
card_picked_player = cards[player_picked-1]
card_picked_computer = cards[computer_picked-1]
```

You can also select directly from the list if you don't need the numeric value.

```
card_picked_player = random.choice(cards)
card_picked_computer = random.choice(cards)
```